# How to mock flask.request with unittest?

Tags: python, flask, mocking, python-import, python-unittest

In my application I have a class that is called from a flask service. This class takes some attributes from the flask.request object, so I want to mock them.

An example of the implementation that I have is:

#### myClassHelper.py

```
from flask import request

class MyClassHelper:

    def __init__(self, addRequestData=False):
        self.attribute = 'something'
        self.path = request.path if addRequestData else None

    def __str__(self):
        return 'attribute={0}; path={1};'.format(self.attribute, self.path)
```

#### myClassHelperTest.py

```py
from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

import flask

from myClassHelper import MyClassHelper


class MyClassHelperTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.path = '/path'

        self.unmock = {}
        self.unmock['flask.request'] = flask.request

        flask.request = MagicMock(path='/path')


    def tearDown(self):
        flask.request = self.unmock['flask.request']

    def test_printAttributes(self):
        expectedResult = 'attribute=something; path={0};'.format(self.path)
        result = str(MyClassHelper(addRequestData=True))
        self.assertEqual(expectedResult, result)
```

The problem comes when I do the import `from myClassHelper import MyClassHelper`. This goes to the import `from flask import request` inside MyClassHelper. So the mock in the setUp method of the test class, it's not being applied.

This can be solved by just importing flask and accessing to the path attribute like `flask.request.path`. But I would like to avoid importing the full flask module.

Is there any way to create a unit test for a method that uses attributes from flask.request, mocking them and without using the flask test client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be a way but unit testing code like this is going to cause you troubles anyway. The SUT is accessing global state that is managed by another module, thus your tests need to properly set up that global state. This can be done either by using that another module as is, which you don't want for good reasons (plus it wouldn't be unit testing anymore), or by monkey-patching it. This is often tricky (as you already found out) and brittle (your tests will break if you change the way you import things in the production code; why should that happen if the relevant behavior has not changed?)

The fix for this kind of problems is making your objects ask for the things they need instead of looking for them in global state. So if all an instance of `MyClassHelper` needs is a path, just make it ask for a path. Let the calling code figure out where the path should come from. Specifically your tests can easily provide canned paths.

This is how your test would look if you follow this principle:

```
class MyClassHelperTest(TestCase):
    def test_printAttributes(self):
        expectedResult = 'attribute=something; path=/path;'
        result = str(MyClassHelper('/path'))
        self.assertEqual(expectedResult, result)
```

Much simpler than before. And this is how you make it pass:

```
class MyClassHelper:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.attribute = 'something'
        self.path = path

    def __str__(self):
        return 'attribute={0}; path={1};'.format(self.attribute, self.path)
```

You do not really need `attribute` if the behavior in the test is all you want. I left it there in order to deviate less from your original code. I assume you have other tests that show why it is actually needed.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I'll apply those changes to my classes to simplify them and avoid future issues with testing